# Pie Chart Display member

Tags: c#, charts, visualization, pie-chart, display

I'm using a pie chart in visual studio 2010 but I don't know how to set the values on display (the values that showed on each slice).
I need to use a different value member that the X and Y values.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: yes, all I had to do is to go to properties --> series --> Lable --> IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

Comment: But that will show the y-values, no?

Comment: Yes, in my case it was enough.I'm sorry but I didn't find a more complicated answer.
If you find an answer you are welcomed to tell me,it would help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In a **Pie Chart** you only need to use the `Y-Values`.

So if you have a `DataSource data` with a Y-Value called `"value"` you can use this to bind:

```
 yourSeries.Points.DataBindY(data,  "value");
```

You can also use this, more general binding method:

```
 yourSeries.Points.DataBind(data, "", "value", "");
```

Note how the first, i.e. the `X-Value` is left empty; all points are always added **indexed** anyway. The last string `otherfields` would be for extended  properties.

And there is even another way to bind the `Points` of a `Series`:

```
 yourSeries.Points.DataBindXY(data, "somePropery", data, "value");
```

Note that here you can use **two different** data sources. But you can't leave the name string of the first one empty, even though the actual values will be ignored againm as with any Pie chart..

Besides binding the the `Points` you could also use other binding methods, [see here for a discussion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456766.aspx) or the pros and cons..!

Also note that the first `DataPoint`, i.e. the first slice starts at 0°. If you want to start it at the top set a ['Custom attribute'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456700%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) : [`PieStartAngle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489224%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) :

```
yourSeries["PieStartAngle"] = "270";
```

To display the values you can set this:

```
yourSeries.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

To move the labels off the slices use this:

```
yourSeries["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
```