# How to use Winform charts with data source?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a pie chart and I want to populate it with a column from database table.

```
|**Nacionality**|**NumAdultos|
|  Portugal     |     2      |<----
|  Ireland      |     4      |<----
|  Angola       |     2      |<---- I want this data to my pie chart
|  Portugal     |     1      |<----
```

Edit- My problem now is that my code repeats the string values in the XValueMember.

```
        List<Historico> lista = new List<Historico>();

        chartNacionalidade.Titles.Add("Nacionalidade");
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString("Hotel")))
        {
            var dados = connection.Query<Historico>($"SELECT Nacionalidade, NumAdultos FROM dbo.Registos_Historico").ToList();
            lista = dados;

        }
        chartNacionalidade.DataSource = lista;
        chartNacionalidade.Series["Nacionalidade"].XValueMember = "Nacionalidade";
        chartNacionalidade.Series["Nacionalidade"].YValueMembers = "NumAdultos";
```

Comment: 1) do not bind the whole chart but the points of a series! There a many many examples around. 2) Your data are strings? How should they make up a Pie chart???

Comment: @TaW i managed to insert the data I want to my chart but now my problem is that it repeats the XValueMember (Note: I updated the question)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that but do note that in a  Pie chart only the y-members matter. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387122/pie-chart-display-member/36389964#36389964)

Comment: @TaW ok i will explain better. I have data with nacionality of a client and the number of people checked in. What I want is a pie chart with thoses values. My problem is the nacionality data repeats (As you can see above in my table, there are two client from Portugal, i want to have only one slice for portugal with the sum of the number of clients but the problem is that it gives two slices for Portugal)

Comment: Ah, ok. You first need to create a proper query then, usually be grouping the data by nationality. Maybe like so `"SELECT Nacionalidade, Sum(NumAdultos) FROM dbo.Registos_Historico GROUP BY Nacionalidade"`

Comment: @TaW you'r query worked! But now my problem is the chart is not showing up

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to change part of the query to use a named expression: `SUM(NumAdultos) as sum`. Did you set the valuemembers? Can  you show the new code?  - What do you mean by 'not showing up'? Is it empty or invisible?

Comment: @TaW my code is the same thing, I only modified the query

Comment: The pie chart itself doesnt show but the data by the side of the chart shows up

Comment: Now it shows up by doing what you said `SUM(NumAdultos) as Soma` thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

Credits to [@TaW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3152130/taw) for this answer.

```
chartNacionalidade.Titles.Add("Nacionalidade");
using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString("Hotel")))
{
       var dados = connection.Query($"SELECT Nacionalidade, Sum(NumAdultos) as Soma FROM dbo.Registos_Historico GROUP BY Nacionalidade").ToList();
       chartNacionalidade.DataSource = dados;
}

chartNacionalidade.Series["Nacionalidade"].XValueMember = "Nacionalidade";
chartNacionalidade.Series["Nacionalidade"].YValueMembers = "Soma";
chartNacionalidade.Series["Nacionalidade"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```